# Date Countdown Timer In React

Tags: html, reactjs

Trying to integrate the [react-date-countdown-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-countdown-timer) package into my react app. I don't really know what I am doing but I'm assuming its a simple fix. Here is my code

```
import DateCountdown from 'react-date-countdown-timer';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div> 
        <DateCountdown dateTo='January 01, 2023 10:00:00 GMT+03:00' callback={()=>alert('Hello')}  />
    </div>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

I've tried wrapping in another div element but nothing seems to work.TIA